# Importing data from MS Analysis Service to SQL Server database using DAX query

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I try to import data from SSAS to a MSDB table using Import/Export wizard. This is working pretty fine, but now I try to transfer a column (of type `nvarchar(4000)`) to a MSDB and the import doesn't work.

I figured out that the wizard only receive the first 255 characters.
As workaround I retrieve the column in 255 char in 16 packages and concatenate them after the report.

```
--DAX for temp table
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        Investigation[Investigation],
        "Examination01", Left(max(Investigation[Examination]), 255),
        "Examination02", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 1 * 256, 255),
        "Examination03", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 2 * 256, 255),
        "Examination04", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 3 * 256, 255),
        "Examination05", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 4 * 256, 255),
        "Examination06", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 5 * 256, 255),
        "Examination07", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 6 * 256, 255),
        "Examination08", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 7 * 256, 255),
        "Examination09", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 8 * 256, 255),
        "Examination10", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 9 * 256, 255),
        "Examination11", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 10 * 256, 255),
        "Examination12", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 11 * 256, 255),
        "Examination13", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 12 * 256, 255),
        "Examination14", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 13 * 256, 255),
        "Examination15", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 14 * 256, 255),
        "Examination16", mid(max(Investigation[Examination]), 15 * 256, 255)
    )
```

```
/*SQL for concatenate in new table*/
DELETE Investigation

INSERT INTO [Investigation] 
    SELECT [Investigation], [Examination01] + [Examination02] + [Examination03] + [Examination04] + [Examination05] + [Examination06] + [Examination07] + [Examination08] + [Examination09] + [Examination10] + [Examination11] + [Examination12] + [Examination13] + [Examination14] + [Examination15] + [Examination16]
    FROM [Investigation_Temp]

DELETE Investigation_Temp
```

Is there a simpler way to get all 4000 chars in one step?

Warm regards

Comment: I would suggest *not* putting data into the `msdb` database; that's a system database. Use your own user database.

Comment: *"I figured out that the wizard only receive the first 255 characters"* Are you sure you're not just not configuring the column's definition properly..?

Comment: Sorry. Of course I use a database table.

Comment: I can't configure the column property for transfer from SSAS, so far I see. When I use flat file import (data exported as csv before) all data can be imported directly.